# append suggestions to searchbox when search input is cleared

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search bar with autocompletion feature. At first on click of search input all the suggestions are added and then I can search for a particular word but when I clear the search input(erase the input field) All the suggestions should be displayed but the list is shown empty on clear of search input tag

How can I resolve this?

```js
  var proj_names=[]
   recent_content={'projects':[{'project_name':'test1'},{'project_name':'test2'},{'project_name':'test3'}]}
   recent_content['projects'].map((val)=>{
         proj_names.push(val["project_name"])
    $('.results').append(`<li class='search-list'>`+val["project_name"]+`</li>`)
    })

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
  let projArray = [];
  
  if(e.target.value){
    projArray = proj_names.filter(proj => proj.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value));
    projArray = projArray.map(proj_names => `<li class='search-list'>${proj_names}</li>`)
  }

  showprojectArray(projArray);
});

function showprojectArray(projArray){
  const html = !projArray.length ? '' : projArray.join('');
  document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
#custom-search-input {
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;

}
.form-control{
  border-radius: 0;
}
#custom-search-input .search-query {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-right: 4px \9;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px \9;
  border: 1px solid   #494949 ;
  /* border-right-style: none; */
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#custom-search-input button {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  padding: 2px 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ion-android-search{
  font-size: 150%;
}
.btn-danger{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.search-query:focus + button {
  z-index: 3;   
}
.search-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


.search-form input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search-form .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search-form .results li { display: block }

.search-form .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search-form .results li:first-child:before, .search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -2px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search-form .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search-form .results li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-form .results li span { font-weight: 200 }

.search-form .results li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  /* background: url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat; */
}

.search-form .results li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #28be9a #28be9a #28be9a;
  background-color: #28be9a;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12 ">
                                <form class="search-form">
                                <input type="text" id="myInput" class="  search-query form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" />
                               
                                <ul class="results" >
                               </ul>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the else block for event.target.value case.

```
if(e.target.value){
    projArray = proj_names.filter(proj => proj.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value));
    projArray = projArray.map(proj_names => `<li class='search-list'>${proj_names}</li>`)
  } else {
     // when e.target.value is empty show entire array.i.e. proj_names
     projArray = proj_names.map(proj_name => return `<li>${proj_name}</li>`)
  }
```

Comment: I want to appear it as a list its shown in single line